# How to compute the mode of a multinomial hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given a multinomial hypergeometric distribution, say doing $n$ draws from an urn with $k_i$ balls of color $i$, how can I compute the mode, that is the most probably outcome?

Simple example: I have $k_1=4, k_2=3, k_3=5$ and I do 8 draws. Enumerating all possibilities, I found $(3, 2, 3)$ to be the mode. How can I compute this without enumerating, for arbitrary many colors?

Edit:
Another less trivial example
2 draws, k=[20  8  2].
The rounding approach suggested by @BGM yields [1, 1, 0], while the mode actually seems to be [2, 0, 0].

The best I found so far is this paper: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1081/STA-120022706 which seems relatively obscure (from 2003, 3 citations), which proposes an algorithm. They claim that every the mode of the final distribution is a mode for the (two-color) hypergeometric induced by each color, which doesn't seem to be the case for the example I gave above:
Looking at the binary case with 30 balls and 20 positive balls, the mode is 1 positive ball, not two.

Comment: My guess: Similar to what we did in maximizing the multinomial likelihood, the mode should be located near $\displaystyle  X_i = n\frac {k_i} {\sum_i k_i}$. In your example it will be approximately $(2.67, 2, 3.33)$. So $(3, 2, 3 )$ should be a natural first trial (and it succeeded). Maybe there is some efficient algorithm to find this out neatly.

Comment: Naive rounding might result in k_i summing up to more or less than the number of draws, though, right?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout: Finucan, H. M. “The Mode of a Multinomial Distribution.” Biometrika, vol. 51, no. 3/4, [Oxford University Press, Biometrika Trust], 1964, pp. 513–17, https://doi.org/10.2307/2334165.

The author describes an algorithm that uses the binomial cross-sections to produce candidate modes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).